# Trouble looping to a point in input validation code

Tags: python, loops, validation, while-loop, integer

I have not been able to figure out how to loop my code back to a specific point, I have 2 loop points and the first one works fine but I can't get the second one to work as I have to define the integer variable "num_stores_int" but if I do, then the "while" loop doesn't work. See my code for where those points are.

Here's my code:

```
num_stores = ("")
num_stores_int = int(num_stores)
while num_stores.isnumeric() == False:
    while num_stores_int > 10: #This is where I want it to loop to 
        num_stores = input ("\n To start, please enter the amount of stores you own: ")
        if num_stores.isnumeric() == True:
            num_stores_int = int(num_stores)
            if num_stores_int > 10: #this is where I want the "while" loop to validate the integer being less than 10
                print (" Sorry, this sales tracker can track a maximum of 10 stores.\n Here, try that again, I'll reboot it for you.\n")
                print (" -----------------------REBOOTING------------------------")
            if num_stores_int >= 5:
                print ("\n Hmm, interesting, you'd think someone with that many \n stores would be able to afford a better sales tracker.")
                print (" Well, I guess you're stuck with me! MUHAHAHAHA!!......\n\n Anyway,")
                print (f" clearly big business person, you own {num_stores_int} stores.\n I'm gonna need you to tell me where each one is")
            else:
                num_stores_int = int(num_stores)
                print (f" Alright... so, random business person, you have {num_stores_int} stores.\n Now, I'm going to need you to tell me where each one is")
        else:
            print ("\n Hey, uhh, you're going to have to write a number for the\n amount of stores you've got, letters and decimals don't \n really work. Here, try again, I'll reboot it for you.\n")
            print (" -----------------------REBOOTING------------------------")
```

Comment: Change `if num_stores_int >= 5:` to `elif num_stores_int >= 5:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I must've poorly explained what was wrong but I just tried something and it worked.

```
def restart():
    num_stores = ("")
    while num_stores.isnumeric() == False: 
        num_stores = input ("\n To start, please enter the amount of stores you own: ")
        if num_stores.isnumeric() == True:
            num_stores_int = int(num_stores)
            if num_stores_int > 10:
                print ("\n Sorry, this sales tracker can track a maximum of 10 stores.\n Here, try that again, I'll reboot it for you.\n")
                print (" -----------------------REBOOTING------------------------")
                restart()
            elif num_stores_int >= 5:
                print ("\n Hmm, interesting, you'd think someone with that many \n stores would be able to afford a better sales tracker.")
                print (" Well, I guess you're stuck with me! MUHAHAHAHA!!......\n\n Anyway,")
                print (f" clearly big business person, you own {num_stores_int} stores. I'm gonna\n need you to tell me where each one is")
            else:
                num_stores_int = int(num_stores)
                print (f" Alright... so, random business person, you have {num_stores_int} stores.\n Now, I'm going to need you to tell me where each one is")
        else:
            print ("\n Hey, uhh, you're going to have to write a number for the\n amount of stores you've got, letters and decimals don't \n really work. Here, try again, I'll reboot it for you.\n")
            print (" -----------------------REBOOTING------------------------")
restart()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not super clear what you are looking for, but I believe that your outer `while` loop is meant to keep asking the user for input when they input something that is not numeric?

I would only wrap that `while` loop around the code that asks for user input, as follows:

```
num_stores = ("")
num_stores_int = 0
while num_stores_int < 10: #This is where I want it to loop to
    num_stores = input ("\n To start, please enter the amount of stores you own:")
    while num_stores.isnumeric() == False:
        print ("\n Hey, uhh, you're going to have to write a number for the\n amount of stores you've got, letters and decimals don't \n really work. Here, try again, I'll reboot it for you.\n")
        print (" -----------------------REBOOTING------------------------")
        num_stores = input ("\n To start, please enter the amount of stores you own:")

    num_stores_int = int(num_stores)
    if num_stores_int > 10: #this is where I want the "while" loop to validate the integer being less than 10
        print (" Sorry, this sales tracker can track a maximum of 10 stores.\n Here, try that again, I'll reboot it for you.\n")
        print (" -----------------------REBOOTING------------------------")
    elif num_stores_int >= 5:
        print ("\n Hmm, interesting, you'd think someone with that many \n stores would be able to afford a better sales tracker.")
        print (" Well, I guess you're stuck with me! MUHAHAHAHA!!......\n\n Anyway,")
        print (f" clearly big business person, you own {num_stores_int} stores.\n I'm gonna need you to tell me where each one is")
    else:
        print (f" Alright... so, random business person, you have {num_stores_int} stores.\n Now, I'm going to need you to tell me where each one is")
```

Comment: Yeah, the outer while loop is working for me but the inner one isn't because I have to define the integer variable num_stores_int in order to check if it's under the number 10 but if I do, it'll take the already defined value and not the one the user inputs and so doesn't work

Comment: @Clandestinity Could you be more specific about what doesn't work with the code I posted

Comment: oooh shoot I didn't notice the change and thought you just reposted my same code. Wow, I didn't expect that to work. Thank you so much man!!

Comment: @Clandestinity I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: Yikes that obvious xD, Thank you I was looking for something to mark it as the right answer. I'm sorry, it's late and my brain is totally fried XD

Comment: @Clandestinity All good, thank you!

Comment: yo sorry for cancelling the thing I just realized it didn't fix the problem. It's my bad, I explained it poorly but I just tried something and it worked. Thank you for the help anyway!